What is the purpose of the array resistors 51R between MCU and the RGB LCD TFT data lines?
I'm trying to make a TFT LCD controller board. The board would for an ARM MCU to control a 24-bit RGB LCD panel, in a handheld device.
In many controller boards got from a well known China supplier, I see there are many array resistors between the MCU controller and the LCD panel, marked "101" and "103" code. Also a schematic image got from a discussion thread (below), that mentioning "51R x4" array.
Edit: The discussion thread that the schematic image came was: https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-touchgfx-and-gui/rgb666/td-p/230306
I learned from some Application Notes for LCD display controller on STM32 MCU etc, and from some market available Discovery board schematics, there are no such resistor appears.
Edit: Application Note: AN4861: Introduction to LCD-TFT display controller (LTDC) on STM32 MCUs.
Question is, what is the purpose of the array resistors (51R, 101, 103...) between MCU and the RGB LCD TFT data lines? Do I need to add them in the design of my own controller PCB?



Search the interweb for 'series termination resistors', you'll find plenty on the subject.

The 51 ohm resistors are for series damping to reduce ringing and improve signal integrity.
It may very well be that the STM32 allows varying the drive strength so that the output impedance can be controlled without adding series damping. If they omit the resistors, it’s a pretty safe bet that you can too.

OK thank you, you mentioned the "series damping resistor" keywords that allows me focusing to learn about.
